# Postgres Create JSON Count of Row Value

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to create a view with aggregated data displayed as a json object:

```
 thing_named_not_unique | emergency_code 
------------------------+----------------
foo                     |  1
foo                     |  2
foo                     |  1
bar                     |  1
bar                     |  2
```

To have the results be

```
 thing_named_not_unique | emergency_code_counts 
------------------------+----------------
foo                     |  {'1': 2, '2': 1}
bar                     |  {'1': 1, '2': 1}
```

I'm pretty new to Postgres JSON functions and can't figure out how to build an aggregate for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to aggregate twice. The first aggregation is to calculate the count of emergency codes per "thing". The second aggregation then aggregates the counts for each thing:

```
select thing_named_not_unique, jsonb_object_agg(emergency_code, cnt) as emergency_code_counts
from (
  select thing_named_not_unique, emergency_code, count(*) as cnt
  from the_table
  group by thing_named_not_unique, emergency_code
) t
group by thing_named_not_unique
order by thing_named_not_unique
```